# How do I connect a TP Link Router to a Unifi Express?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, unifi

I am very new to networking. I got a Unifi Express which I have configured and is working. I am able to connect all the computers and IoT devices in my house. However, the range is limited and I would like to see if I can extend it out a little further without additional expense. I have a TP Link Archer A7 router that I would like to attach to the Unifi Express. I have tried plugging it into the Unifi Express Lan port, but it does not appear in the Unifi Console or the Tether app.

Is this even possible and if so, how do I connect it?